# Suggestion list within text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, textarea

I want to be able to open dropdown list withing a text area just under the cursor.
just like IDE offer suggest list at the middle of your code.

Do you know any tool that can help me do it? All I can find is the JQuery autocomplete but this only works to a whole text input and not as a pop up inside a text area.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is anything like this... or did you want something like a spell checker? There's a plugin to do that: http://brandonaaron.net/code/spellcheck/docs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a little starting point. Maybe it helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/SNRTp/