# Place drop down menu inside a text box or text area

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to place a **drop down menu** inside a textbox which I created using **HTML** , but I have no idea how to do coding for that.

I found a way to place a image inside a text area but nothing for dropdown menu.

```
$('input:text').css('background','#fff url(images/back.png) center right no-repeat');
```

my idea is to place a drop down menu inside a search box, so user can select what category to search. example: music, video, pictures. but the selection drop down menu should be inside the search box.

my drop down menu code is

```
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>                </ul>
      </li>
```

Any suggestions for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: you can use autoComplete...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070798/suggestion-list-within-text-area

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#appendedDropdownButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @TGH's answer:

CSS:

```
#dropdown
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
body textarea
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<textarea></textarea>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nJGK/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to overlay the dropdown using z-index and absolute positioning.
Specify absolute positioning and a z-index for the dropdown through css.